# Custom Error Page is not working on live server

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, global-asax, custom-errors

I have implemented Custom Error Functionality in my project, and its working on local IIS but not working on live server. I have implemented this functionality using Global.asax file and i am calling my custom error action method in my custom error controller in MVC. I have published and run on local IIS and its work well,but on live server.

my Global.asax.cs file

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    //do not register HandleErrorAttribute. use classic error handling mode
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
}

protected void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LogException(Server.GetLastError());

    CustomErrorsSection customErrorsSection = (CustomErrorsSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/customErrors");
    string defaultRedirect = customErrorsSection.DefaultRedirect;
    if (customErrorsSection.Mod e== CustomErrorsMode.On)
    {
        var ex = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();

        Server.ClearError();
        var routeData = new RouteData();
        routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Common");
        routeData.Values.Add("action", "CustomError");

        if (ex is HttpException)
        {
            var httpException = (HttpException)ex;
            var code = httpException.GetHttpCode();
            routeData.Values.Add("status", code);
        }
        else
        {
            routeData.Values.Add("status", 500);
        }

        routeData.Values.Add("error", ex);

        IController errorController = new Test.Controllers.CommonController();
        errorController.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
    }
}
```

My Custom error Controller and its action method

```
public ActionResult CustomError(int status, Exception error)
{
    var model = new CustomErrorModel();
    model.Code = status;
    model.Description = Convert.ToString(error);
    Response.StatusCode = status;
    return View(model);
}
```

So what should I do?

Comment: I suggest you provide some code for us to look at..

Comment: can we see some code? Is you web.config setup correctly? You haven't given us much information to go on.

Comment: What do you mean by Local IIS and Live IIS?? I think you need to check IIS configurations.

Comment: Have you solved this? Actually I've come across this very problem, when Casini does call Application_Error when no route matched, but IIS Express does not (it shows its standard 404 error report). Is there a way to get both HTTP ERROR 404 status and custom error page in IIS Express, I wonder (I didn't check all this on IIS yet)?

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem where errors on live IIS server weren't showing custom error pages (which return proper HttpStatusCodes) but it WAS working on local IIS (localhost address using default website - *not* Cassini). They should have worked exactly the same I would have thought - anyway this web.config setting fixed it.

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough"></httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Note that my setup uses Application_Error in global.asax and just this other web.config setting:

```
<customErrors mode="On">
    <!-- There is custom handling of errors in Global.asax -->
</customErrors>
```

Answer (score 1):

2 approaches

**Route Method**

```
// We couldn't find a route to handle the request. Show the 404 page. 
routes.MapRoute("Error", "{*url}", new { controller = "Error", action = "CustomError" } );
```

or

**Custom Error Handler in Web.config**:

```
<customErrors mode="On" >
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/CatchallController/CustomError" />
</customErrors>
```

The condition raised by no route matching is a 404. This way you direct all non-match to your `~/CatchallController/CustomError`

Comment: But both these approaches result into `200 OK` status in browser, while the desired behaviour is to get `404`. Actually I've come across this very problem, when Casini does call `Application_Error` when no route matched, but IIS Express does not (it shows its standard 404 error report). Is there a way to get both `HTTP ERROR 404` status and custom error page in IIS Express (I didn't check all this on IIS yet)?

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov, It's neem a month since I saw this OP. Still wrapping my mind around it again. From looking at it now, I thought goal was to catch 404 elegantly...